# I am trying to run a program on Android Studio, however an emulator error pops up

Tags: android-emulator

I was creating a program in Android studio and I tried to run it, however the Nexus 5 Virtual Machine wouldn't load because of this error:

Emulator: Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.